# What sort of triangle will give minimum value for (a+b)?

Tags: geometry

If there is a triangle with sides a,b and c and the length of c is constant (as is its perpendicular distance from the opposite vertex), then what sort of triangle will give minimum value for (a+b)? Obtuse-angled, right-angled or acute-angled? Can you prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: You may want to draw a picture yourself if you have no idea how to tackle the question.

Comment: To add to the question, click on "edit" beneath the question itself.

Comment: Just to say, unless I am misreading the problem, the answer will depend on the various values.  If $h$, the fixed altitude, is extremely small, the triangle is clearly obtuse.  If $h$ is enormous, then the triangle is clearly acute...(just draw the pictures).  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: ok i should probably add like a drawing, please wait.

Comment: @lulu: I think that $a, b, c$ are meant to indicate the lengths of the sides rather than the measures of the angles; if so, it seems to me that for $h$ small, there's an obvious choice for the location of the vertex opposite side $c$ (and that this doesn't result in an obtuse triangle).

Comment: @JohnHughes Yeah they're the sides

Comment: also i can't upload images at the moment, so sorry.

Comment: @JohnHughes  Yes, I assumed that $a,b,c$ were the sides.  I am taking it as clear that the minimal triangle is isosceles (though that certainly merits an argument).  For small $h$ it is obtuse, for large $h$ it is acute.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I was thinking of the angles on side c, which should always both be acute; the angle opposite side c could, as you observe, be either acute or obtuse. I suppose that this means the triangle is obtuse (and so, apparently, am I). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Minimum value of $a+b$ is achieved if triangle $ABC$ is isosceles ($AC=BC$).

**Proof:**

Draw a line $p$ parallel to line $AB$ at a fixed distance defined in the task. Vertex $C$ of any given triange has to be on the line $p$. Draw point $B'$ symmetric to $B$ with respect to line $p$. Draw line $AB'$, intersecting line $p$ at point $C'$. Triangle $ABC'$ is obviously isosceles with $AC'=BC'$.

But:

$$a+b=AC+BC=AC+CB'\quad \ge \quad AB'=AC'+C'B'=AC'+C'B$$

The minimum possible value is achieved only for $C=C'$ or when the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles.

Comment: Nice argument (+1).  Sure beats the argument via Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Using calculus. Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Note that the side $AB=c$ and the altitude $h$ are constant. The point $C$ is mobile (flexible) and $x$ needs to be found so that $a+b$ is minimum. So:
$$a+b=\sqrt{h^2+(c-x)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+h^2}=f(x) \Rightarrow \\
f'(x)=\frac{-2(c-x)}{2\sqrt{h^2+(c-x)^2}}+\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}=0 \Rightarrow \\
x^2(h^2+(c-x)^2)=(c-x)^2(x^2+h^2) \Rightarrow \\
x=\frac c2\\
f'(0)=-\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+h^2}}<0; f'(c)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+h^2}}>0 \Rightarrow f\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)=\sqrt{c^2+4h^2} \ \ \text{is minimum}.$$
Which implies $a=b$ and the triangle is isosceles.

Depending on the side $c$ and the altitude $h$, the triangle can be acute, right or obtuse.